# Customising Angular Material input - removing bottom border when autocomplete visible

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Material with Angular and want to customise an input so it looks nice with autocomplete. How can I remove the border of the input at the bottom when the autocomplete results are visible?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2eob6d

I'm not sure what the best way to do it is, should I add CSS rules to override material's css? Not sure what to do.

Comment: So we can better help you, and so we can learn something while we help you, please add what you've already tried to do to remove the border _and_ add what you've already researched.

Comment: Haven't tried anything, asking advice what to do, not necessarily a code solution

Answer (score 1):

Add some class to your form field something like

```
<mat-form-field class="autocomplete-container">
```

Then use this class with `mat-focused` class to hide bottom border 
Add following in your style.css

```
 .autocomplete-container.mat-focused .mat-form-field-outline .mat-form-field-outline-start,
.autocomplete-container.mat-focused .mat-form-field-outline .mat-form-field-outline-gap,
.autocomplete-container.mat-focused .mat-form-field-outline .mat-form-field-outline-end
{
    border-bottom: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

[Stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2eob6d-kgv9av)

Comment: Your code removes all the border, but OP wants only bottom to get removed

Comment: Look like he update the question later on will recheck my ans